# DataSource ,XADataSource and JTA

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, transactions, datasource

I am trying to understand **local and global transaction** in JPA. 
In JPA Specs I found that there are two type of transaction that is **RESOURCE_LOCAL** and **JTA** ***aka GlobalTransaction***.
But what I read somewhere that to participate in global transaction **Datasource** should be **XA-complient**.
When we declare `<jta-datasource>` in **persistence.xml** . It is `javax.sql.DataSource` type ,It is  not `javax.sql.XADataSource` type and It still takes part in Global Transaction .It always confuses me.
Please provide me a clear understanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to understand reading JTA Spec after and after and It says:

***When there are multiple transcational resources e.g. Datasources,JMS queues etc, taking part in JTA they all must be XA-Complient . When there is single resource, condition does not necessarily hold true means It may or may not XA-Complient;***